# Find a basis for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$T = \{p \in P_2 \mid p(0) = 0\}$ and $S = \{p \in P_2 \mid p(1) = 0\}$.

Find a basis for:
a) T
b) S
c) T and S

My solution:
$S = ax^2 + bx + c$
$p(1) = 1 + 1 + c$
     $c = 2$
$s = \{ax^2 , x\}$
$x^2$ and $x$ form the basis for the subspace $s$.

Is that correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, your solution is incorrect.

$$
S= \{p \in P_2 \mid p(1)=0\}
$$

So a generic $p \in S$ would look like $p=ax^2+bx+c$ then

$p(1)=a\cdot1^2+b\cdot1+c=0 \iff c=-a-b$

So we can replace that in our generic $p$:

$$
p=ax^2+bx+(-a-b)
$$
Rearranging...
$$
p=a(x^2-1)+b(x-1)
$$
So you base $B=\{x^2-1,x-1\}$